# Problema al importar modulos Python

Tags: python, class

tengo un problema que no le encuentro solucion, el cual es que no puedo importar clases de modulos o los mismos modulos en python, recien voy iniciando y hago ejercicios simples, pero siempre que tengo que importar clases, me sale el mensaje de "cannot import name 'x' from 'modulo x'" al ejecutarlo, es algo asi:

```
from Models import db, Streamers
```

Tengo un modulo llamado Models y 2 clases llamada db y streamers(es un ejercicio de tutorial xD) pero aunque el mismo IDE me diga que esas clases existen, cuando lo ejecuto me sale el mensajito ese, asi que busco alguna solucion, por cierto, uso el IDE de Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Puedes añadir más información a la pregunta? El contenido de Models y la estructura del proyecto por ejempo

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.